# Does induced topology preserve density?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau )$ a topological space and $D \subseteq X$ dense in $(X, \tau)$. Show that if $A \in \tau$, then  $A\cap D$ is dense in subspace $A$.

I have already proven that the intersection of two dense subsets in $X$, one of which is open is dense. Can I enjoy this demonstration?
I feel like we're using the induced topology for subspace A. In this case the induced topology preserves density, compactness as well? Is that what I'm thinking?

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that every nonempty set which is open in the subspace $A$ has a nonempty intersection with $D$. But if $A\in \tau$ then the sets which are open in $A$ are exactly the sets of $\tau$ included in $A$ for which, by assumption, you know that (if nonempty) they have a nonempty intersection with $D$.

Comment: "You have to show that every *nonempty* set which is open..."

Comment: yes, I fix the answer